# "How's stuff?" | "How are your project's going?" | "What's new in your world?"

Tags: salutation

Saying "How are you?" or "How's it going?" is well documented in any German 101 class. But I'm curious how one does this in the context of business. I note that most of my conversations with coworkers I don't commonly associate with usually adhere to the following pattern:

Hi -> How are you? -> How are your projects?

In literaly English to German, one would say:

Wie sind Ihre Projekte?

But I'm curious how one could do this and sound more native? Further, I work in software. We tend to be informal, even in the German world. Is there a way to ask this colloquially and sound more authentic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem of intercultural interaction mostly. In Germany, people having business with each other **never** ask **Wie geht's?** because that's a personal question. The same with asking about other projects a person does.

When you ask something like that, you will make your German business partner feel very uncomfortable because you showed interest in her/him. Of course you didn't. You aren't interested at all, it's an empty formula. At least for people from the U.S. In German speaking countries, it's asking a friend how things are going. The U.S. habit of calling people by first name doesn't help either.

So … don't ask something like that if you aren't friends. At least not in German. If you do it in English, people may assume *ah, that's the weird U.S. introduction, tell one of those U.S. white lies and it's all okay.*

Go straight so the point, tell what you want. That's authentic German.

> Hallo Sebastian,
>
> ich habe einen Bug in deiner Software gefunden, die Datei modules/GUI/main.c wirft beim Kompilieren immer einen Fehler.
>
> [Fehlerprotokoll]
>
> Oder mache ich was falsch?
>
> Gruß,
>
> Dirk

Comment: If it's a personal meeting, it is not unusual to ask something directly related to the encounter: "Hatten Sie eine gute Anreise?", "Konnten Sie gut herfinden?", "Hat beim Hotel-Check-in alles funktioniert?" etc.

Comment: Yes, because these aren't personal questions but cover a specific topic connected to that meeting.

Comment: If you have a long enough business together in, lets say, projects it is not unusual to ask also about the family as you know each other long enough.

Comment: That's right, but not as a greeting. I know people from the U.S. doing that in any single letter they write to me … it's an empty formula.